# My rpi connects multiple times to the router

Tags: raspbian, networking, linux

[image: router active connections]
[image: etc/network/interfaces]

Why does my rpi connect so many times at once to the internet. For the record I have one rpi2 and one rpi3 and they share the same sdcard, I just switch it between them. I tried both the ethernet as the wlan and in both cases it happens. It already caused problems as I was trying to install a program felt like it froze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you fiddled with the settings. See the following for how to fix it.

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)